# std::vector size remains zero after trying to fill it

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to use vector efficiently. So I reserve memory first and then use the vector. But after I try to fill the vector using [] operator, the size of vector remains zero. Why does this happen?

```
vector Vec; 
Vec.reserve(10); 
Vec[0] = 2.0; 
Vec[1] = 3.0;
...
```

Comment: You are mixing reserve with resize.

Comment: Why mixing? I don't want initializing with resizing

Comment: why dont you just push into the vector?

Comment: Since I want to put in special order

Comment: @AndréPuel Of course, there's no point in using `resize` either; he could just construct the vector with the right size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`reserve()` only reserves space in the backing store so subsequent pushed elements don't have to incur a reallocation (until you exceed the reserved space). It doesn't change the actual size of the vector though, so your `Vec[0] =` access is actually running off the end of the vector.

You could use

```
vector Vec;
Vec.resize(10);
Vec[0] = 2.0;
Vec[1] = 3.0;
```

if you want, and the size will be 10. Or if you want the size to only be 2 at this point, but still reserve space to avoid multiple reallocations, you could use

```
vector Vec;
Vec.reserve(10);
Vec.push_back(2.0);
Vec.push_back(3.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

`reserve()` doesn't resize the vector. You need to use `resize()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `reserve` you aren't actually creating elements in the vector. Your assignments are accessing elements that don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector does not automatically expand. Function reserve(size) does not increase the size, it can only make sure you have enough memory for later size expansion.

So instead of the illegal

```
Vec[0] = 2.0;
```

Try

```
Vec.push_back( 2.0 );
```

This will increase the vector size by 1.

By the way, the declaration should be

```
vector<double> Vec;
```

Answer (score 1):

`reserve` has no effect on the size of the vector.  On most
implementations I've used, the following accesses would have
caused the program to terminate.  If it didn't, you probably
compiled with the wrong options.

You should construct the vector directly with a size of 10:

```
std::vector<double> vec( 10 );
```

If the values you are inserting are constants, you can do
something like:

```
static double initVec[] = { 2.0, 3.0 ... };
std::vector<double> vec( begin( initVec ), end( initVec ) );
```

, or if you are using C++11:

```
std::vector<double> vec{ 2.0, 3.0 ... };
```

Both of these methods have the advantage of initializing the
data in the vector directly.